# Chrome does not display images with clip, opacity, translateZ set

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, opacity, clip

I think I may have stumbled upon a bug in Chrome. If you have an image wrapped in a 
parent div which has its position set to absolute, its clip attribute set to any 
value, its webkit-transform "translateZ" to 0px and its opacity below 1, Chrome will not display the image, if the image itself has its position attribute set to absolute.

kind of a mouthful, so check out this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/djdieben/SN3nb/

For me, this displays the image of Einstein in all browsers except Chrome. that is,

- IE7+ (i.e. IE9 in IE7/IE8 mode, I haven't actually tested on IE7 or IE8),
- FF10
- Safari 5.1
- Opera 11

I'm on Chrome 18 beta, but it also fails on Chrome 17. All on Windows 7

Can anyone verify the fiddle for me? Any solutions on how to deal with this problem? I'm working with Adobe's Edge preview, which auto-sets a lot of these CSS-parameters, so just changing the CSS-stylesheet is not an option.

Comment: You should search for an existing bug and if not found file a new one: http://crbug.com/new

Comment: Loaded the url(http://jsfiddle.net/djdieben/SN3nb/) with chromium 15.0.868.0 on ubuntu 10.04, and it could show the image.

Comment: bug is filed, see: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=116291